# Funcion recursiva PHP, obtener hijos

Tags: php, array, funciones

¿Alguien me da una mano? Estoy necesitando crear una función recursiva, que me obtenga el padre y si tiene hijos, es decir que me devuelva slug: padre y si tiene hijos sea `slug: padre/hijo/hijos` y así recursivamente.

MAS DETALLES

La idea es que recorramos el array mostremos primero el padre, volvemos a recorrer el array vemos si tiene hijos y lo concatenamos con el padre y asi recursivamente, la salida deberia ser asi, convengamos que hay un padre bueno, se imprime

"padre"

volvemos a ejecutar la funcion verificando si ese padre tiene childs, y si tenemos entonces devolvemos de vuelta

"padre/hijo"

volveriamos a ejecutar la funcion que verifique de vuelta si childs tiene childs si tiene deberia de devolver asi

"padre/hijo/hijo"

Y asi sucesivamente hasta generar una lista de paths generados con el campo "slug", el resultado final tendria que devolver la lista

"padre"
"padre/hijo"
"padre/hijo/hijo"
"otropadre"
"otropadre/hijo"
"padresinhijo"

esa es mas o menos la idea... no se si me explico.

OTRO PROBLEMA

Me surgio una sugerencia, bueno ahora lo que estamos haciendo es recorrer el array e ir concatenando pade e hijo, ahora necesitariamos que vaya concatenando solo si tiene hijos... supongamos que este es mi array:

```
$rows2 = array(
array(
    'id' => 142,
    'name' => "Cate 1",
    'slug' => "Cate 1",
    'childs' =>

        array(
            'id' => 143,
            'name' => "Cate1 nivel 2",
            'slug' => "Cate1 nivel 2",
            'childs' => array()
        ),
        array( 
            'id' => 144,
            'name' => "Cate1 nivel 3",
            'slug' => "Cate1 nivel 3",
            'childs' => array()
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 145,
            'name' => "Cate1 nivel 4",
            'slug' => "Cate1 nivel 4",
            'childs' => array(
                'id' => 144,
                'name' => "Cate1 nivel 5",
                'slug' => "Cate1 nivel 5",
                'childs' => array()
            )
        )
)),

array(
'id' => 145,
'name' => "Cate 2",
'slug' => "Cate 2",
'childs' => array(
    'id' => 146,
    'name' => "Cate2 nivel 2",
    'slug' => "Cate2 nivel 2",
    'childs' => array()
))
```

);

Si nos fijamos, el array de $rows2 tiene un padre con varios hijos, ahora bien, lo que intento es que me concatene solo 1 hijo con el padre, seria mas o menos asi:

```
Cate 1|Cate1 nivel 2
Cate 1|Cate1 nivel 3
Cate 1|Cate1 nivel 4
```

Y en el caso de tener mas de un nivel que verifique y me concatene tambien con ese nivel, ejemplo con el array id 145 que me quedaria asi:

```
Cate 1|Cate1 nivel 4|Cate1 nivel nivel 5
```

Eso si es que tiene mas niveles, tendria que poder tener una condicion, creo yo.

Este sería mi array y mi función que me trae todo el árbol:

```
 $array = [
  {
    "id": 142,
    "name": "Nombre de la cate 1",
    "slug": "nombre-de-la-cate-1"
    "childs": [
      {
        "id": 143,
        "name": "Cate nivel 2",
        "slug": "cate-nivel-2",
        "childs": [
          {
            "id": 145,
            "name": "Cat nivel 3",
            "slug": "cat-nivel-3",

            "childs": [
              {
                "id": 146,
                "name": "Cat nivel 4",
                "slug": "cat-nivel-4",

                "childs": [
                  {
                    "id": 147,
                    "name": "Cay n5",
                    "slug": "cay-n5",

                    "childs": [
                      {
                        "id": 148,
                        "name": "Cat N6",
                        "slug": "cat-n6",

                        "childs": [],
                        "category_ad_count": 0,


                      },
                      {
                        "id": 149,
                        "name": "Cat N6",
                        "slug": "cat-n6",

                        "childs": [],
                        "category_ad_count": 0,


                      }
                    ],
                    "category_ad_count": 0,
                  }
                ],
                "category_ad_count": 0,
              }
            ],
            "category_ad_count": 0,
          }
        ],
        "category_ad_count": 0,
      },
      {
        "id": 144,
        "name": "Cat 2 nivel 2",
        "slug": "cat-2-nivel-2",
        "childs": [],
        "category_ad_count": 0,

      }
    ],    "category_ad_count": 0,
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Nombre de la cate 2",
    "slug": "nombre-de-la-cate-2"
    "childs": [
      {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "hijo",
        "slug": "hijo",
        "childs": [],
        "category_ad_count": 237,

      },
      {
        "id": 128,
        "name": "PRUEBA DE",
        "slug": "prueba-de",
        "childs": [],
        "category_ad_count": 0,

      },
      {
        "id": 17,
        "name": "hijo2",
        "slug": "hijo2",
        "childs": [],
        "category_ad_count": 198325,

      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "name": "hijo3",
        "slug": "hijo3",
        "childs": [],
        "category_ad_count": 3579,

      },
      {
        "id": 124,
        "name": "prueba",
        "slug": "prueba",
        "childs": [],
        "category_ad_count": 0,

      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "hijo4",
        "slug": "hijo4",
        "childs": [],
        "category_ad_count": 6457,

      },
      {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "hijo5",
        "slug": "hijo5",
        "childs": [
          {
            "id": 135,
            "name": "hijo1",
            "slug": "hijo1",

            "childs": [],
                "category_ad_count": 0,


          },
          {
            "id": 136,
            "name": "hijo2",
            "slug": "hijo2",

            "childs": [],
                "category_ad_count": 0,


          },
          {
            "id": 137,
            "name": "hijo3",
            "slug": "hijo3",

            "childs": [],
                "category_ad_count": 0,


          },
          {
            "id": 138,
            "name": "hijo2",
            "slug": "hijo2",

            "childs": [
              {
                "id": 139,
                "name": "hijo1",
                "slug": "hijo1",

                "childs": [],
                        "category_ad_count": 0,


              },
              {
                "id": 140,
                "name": "hijo2",
                "slug": "hijo2",

                "childs": [],
                        "category_ad_count": 0,


              },
              {
                "id": 141,
                "name": "Otros",
                "slug": "otros",

                "childs": [],
                        "category_ad_count": 0,


              }
            ],
                "category_ad_count": 0,


          }
        ],
        "category_ad_count": 18733,

      },
      {
        "id": 23,
        "name": "sinhijos",
        "slug": "sinhijos",
        "childs": [],
        "category_ad_count": 1841,

      },
      {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "sinhijos2",
        "slug": "sinhijos2",
        "childs": [],
        "category_ad_count": 12172,

      }
    ],
    "category_ad_count": 241345,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "otros2",
    "slug": "otros2"
    "childs": [
      {
        "id": 25,
        "name": "hijo1",
        "slug": "hijo1",
        "childs": [],
        "category_ad_count": 58783,

      },
      {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "hijo2",
        "slug": "hijo2",
        "childs": [],
        "category_ad_count": 2557,

      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "hijo3",
        "slug": "hijo3",
        "childs": [],
        "category_ad_count": 22637,

      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "hijo4",
        "slug": "hijo4",
        "childs": [],
        "category_ad_count": 8761,

      }
    ],
    "category_ad_count": 176319,
  }
];
```

El resultado esperado sería:

```
padre
padre/hijo
padre/hijo/hijo
```

Esta es la función con la que lo estoy recorriendo:

```
function category($array){
    $inicio = '';
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        $inicio .= '<li>'.((is_array($v)) ? $k.category($v) : $v).'</li>';
    }
    return '<ul>'.$inicio.'</ul>';
}

echo category($array);
```

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste hasta ahora (por más que no funcione)? ¿Y cuál es el formato concreto en el que querés que imprima? Estás diciendo `padre/hijo/hijos`, pero ¿cómo se mostrarían con ese formato los diferentes hijos y sus respectivos nietos de esa forma?

Comment: hecho, y el resultado deberia de armarme una ruta con los slug, es decir primero vemos que esta padre, imprimimos padre luego verificamos que ese padre tiene hijo imprimimos padre/hijo y asi recursivamente...
seria:
padre
padre/hijo
padre/hijo/hijo 
y asi, el resultado esperado...

Comment: @Roberto aparentemente estás usando 2 usuarios diferentes. Sería recomendable que usaras el mismo para editar tu pregunta. Sino, cada edición requiere que sea revisada y aprobada., y no podrás comentar acá... Si estás teniendo problemas con esto, selecciona Reportar -> Se necesita la intervención de un moderador y explica tu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto te sirve? no estoy seguro de como queres mostrar los datos

Suponiendo que el array es:

```
$rows = array(
    array(
    'id' => 142,
    'name' => "Cate 1",
    'slug' => "Cate 1",
    'childs' => array(
        'id' => 143,
        'name' => "Cate1 nivel 2",
        'slug' => "Cate1 nivel 2",
        'childs' => array(
            'id' => 144,
            'name' => "Cate1 nivel 3",
            'slug' => "Cate1 nivel 3",
            'childs' => array()
        )
    )),
    array(
    'id' => 145,
    'name' => "Cate 2",
    'slug' => "Cate 2",
    'childs' => array(
        'id' => 146,
        'name' => "Cate2 nivel 2",
        'slug' => "Cate2 nivel 2",
        'childs' => array()
    ))
);
```

***EDIT***

Ahora entiendo mejor lo que quieres lograr, creo que de la siguiente manera estaria ok:

```
$ant="";

foreach($rows as $row){
    array_walk_recursive($row, 'test_print', ["cadena"=>&$ant]);
    echo "\n";
    $ant="";
}

function test_print($item, $key, $ant){
    if($key == "name"){
        if(empty($ant["cadena"]))
            $ant["cadena"] .= $item;
        else
            $ant["cadena"] .= "|".$item;    
        echo  $ant["cadena"]."\n";      
    }
}
```

[Aca](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fb00a797043851eb3083e2282c49e958e8b792ca) Sandbox actualizador con la nueva edicion

Comment: Muchas gracias Leonardo! casi es lo que necesito, en la pregunta agregue mas detalles sobre lo que necesito, para entender mas o menos mejor...

Comment: Buenisimo Leo! Gracias! Funciona super...